# how to move the rectangle faster while clicking on the arrow-button?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

How to make the rectangle moving faster as normal while clicking on the Arrow-Button, and then since i take my finger away it should move with the normal value again.

this is how my code looks like including the animation function :
i tried to increasing the x,y values but its jumping to another square immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the player move at a constant speed of 60 try making it change at a variable speed. I.E.

```
var speed = 60;

...


case 'east':
    gameState.playerPosition.x +=speed;
    break;
case'west':
    gameState.playerPosition.x -=speed;
    break;
case'north':
    gameState.playerPosition.y -=speed;
    break;
case'south':
    gameState.playerPosition.y +=speed;
```

Then instead of changing direction on `keyup` change it and the speed on `keydown`. Then when the `keyup` event fires change the speed back to normal.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    speed = 120;
    if(event.key==='ArrowRight'){
        gameState.direction = "east";
    }else if(event.key==='ArrowLeft'){
       gameState.direction = "west"
    }else if(event.key === 'ArrowUp'){
       gameState.direction = "north"
    }else if(event.key === 'ArrowDown'){
       gameState.direction = "south"
    }
    console.log('Key ' + event.key + ' was pressed.'); 
});   

document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    speed = 60;
});
```

Comment: thianks but this is jumping to the next square. i need to animate it faster and not to increasing the x,y values

Comment: Change frameTime variable, so that it updates faster. You will still want to use the keyup and keydown events as I described, but instead of changing a speed variable change the frameTime.